# i am trying to integrate admob in flutter. it returns null?

Tags: flutter, dart

i am trying to monitize my app using admob but its really hard to implement it in the app, now everything is set but it gives the following error,"The method 'load' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: load()"
can anyone help?

```
import 'package:carousel_pro/carousel_pro.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:animated_dialog/animated_dialog.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
import 'package:firebase_admob/firebase_admob.dart';

class Car extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CarState createState() => _CarState();
}

class _CarState extends State<Car> {
  static String adId = 'ca-app-pub-xxxxx92680942917/5470xxxxxx';
  String appId = 'ca-app-pub-xxxxxx2680942917~612810xxxx';
  MobileAdTargetingInfo targetingInfo;
  BannerAd myBanner;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    MobileAdTargetingInfo(
      keywords: <String>['flutterio', 'beautiful apps'],
      contentUrl: 'https://flutter.io',
      birthday: DateTime.now(),
      childDirected: false,
      designedForFamilies: false,
      gender: MobileAdGender
          .male, // or MobileAdGender.female, MobileAdGender.unknown
      testDevices: <String>[], // Android emulators are considered test devices
    );

    BannerAd(
      adUnitId: adId,
      size: AdSize.fullBanner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("BannerAd event is $event");
      },
    );
  }

  showBanner() {
    myBanner
      // typically this happens well before the ad is shown
      ..load()
      ..show(
        
        // Positions the banner ad 60 pixels from the bottom of the screen
        anchorOffset: 0.0,
        // Positions the banner ad 10 pixels from the center of the screen to the right
        horizontalCenterOffset: 0.0,
        // Banner Position
        // anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
      );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
  ) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal[50],
        body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: Firestore.instance.collection('car').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.data == null)
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  valueColor: new AlwaysStoppedAnimation<Color>(Colors.teal),
                ),
              );

            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Container(
                      child: Card(
                          //shadowColor: Colors.yellow,
                          child: Column(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          //AD
                          showBanner(),
                          // Name Container
                          Container(
                            alignment: Alignment.center,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                color: Colors.teal[300],
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                    topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                                    topLeft: Radius.circular(15))),
                            width: 400,
                            height: 50,
                            child: Text(
                              snapshot.data.documents[index]['item Name'],
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Baloo',
                                fontSize: 25,
                                color: Colors.white,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                          //item Image///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

i deleted rest of the code cuz it is very long and allowed in here.

Answer (score 0):

That's happening because you didn't initialize your banner. I changed your showBanner function and added a new function to initialize it:

```
  BannerAd createBannerAd() {
    return BannerAd(
      adUnitId: BannerAd.testAdUnitId,
      size: AdSize.banner,
      targetingInfo: targetingInfo,
      listener: (MobileAdEvent event) {
        print("BannerAd event $event");
      },
    );
  }

  showBanner() {
        _bannerAd ??= createBannerAd();
        _bannerAd
        ..load()
        ..show( 
        // Positions the banner ad 60 pixels from the bottom of the screen
        anchorOffset: 0.0,
        // Positions the banner ad 10 pixels from the center of the screen to the right
        horizontalCenterOffset: 0.0,
        // Banner Position
        // anchorType: AnchorType.bottom,
      );
  }
```

You can also do this inside the initState method if you want:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    FirebaseAdMob.instance.initialize(appId: "YOUR-APP-ID");
    _bannerAd = createBannerAd()..load();
  }
```

Comment: thanks for answering. it works fine but when i enter my own adUnitId  it doest work and gives this error `Exception has occurred.
PlatformException (PlatformException(load_failed_ad, cannot reload a failed ad, id=896455314, null)) `